# Cast string to UITestControl

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests

To keep it concise, I can do this:

```
UIRvWindow AppWin = new UIRvWindow();

UITestControl path = new UITestControl();

path = AppWin.UnderlyingClass1.UnderLyingClass2;

IEnumerable<WpfButton> collection = path.GetChildren().OfType<WpfButton>();

foreach(WpfButton button in collection)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(button.FriendlyName + " - " + button.DisplayText + " - " + button.Name + " - " + button.AutomationId);
}
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to do this:

```
UIRvWindow AppWin = new UIRvWindow();

UITestControl path = new UITestControl();

string x = "AppWin.UnderlyingClass1.UnderLyingClass2"; 

path = x;

IEnumerable<WpfButton> collection = path.GetChildren().OfType<WpfButton>();

foreach(WpfButton button in collection)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(button.FriendlyName + " - " + button.DisplayText + " - " + button.Name + " - " + button.AutomationId);
}
```

Basically, I have a List of strings and I want to run them through one by one. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you may want to tag the language used here

Comment: Posting a sample code for : `AppWin.UnderlyingClass1.UnderLyingClass2` would be helpful. 
Tried Reflection to load?

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a way to achieve dynamic invocation. Assuming you have a list of type names as strings, then you can do similar to following:

```
List<string> classes = new List<string> { "WindowsFormsApplication1.MyClass1", "WindowsFormsApplication1.MyClass2" };
foreach (var typeName in classes)
{
     Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
     var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

     var result = (type.GetMethod("GetChildren").Invoke(instance, null) as IEnumerable<object>).OfType<WpfButton>();

}
```

If all your classes are inheriting from a base class having virtual `GetChildren()` method in it, then you can reduce a bit of reflection as below:

```
foreach (var typeName in classes)
{
     Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
     var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

     IEnumerable<WpfButton> myButtons = null;
     if(instance is MyBase) //MyBase is base class having virtual GetChildren() and this base class is derived by MyClass1, MyClass2...
     {
          myButtons = (instance as MyBase).GetChildren().OfType<WpfButton>();
     }
}
```

PS reflection might have performance issues if you planning to use over too many types, please use it with caution and proper design goals. 
Hope this help you...